# PHP skip val if key = x

Tags: php, arrays, csv, key

I cannot seem to get this array loop to skip values where the key is 'x'

```
$csv = array();
foreach ($row as $key => $val){
    if($key != 'x' && $key != 'y' && $key != 'z'){
        $csv[] = $val.',';  
    }                   
}
```

If keys are x,y,z they still are added to the csv array.

Comment: you want to skip all key, or any key??

Comment: `if (!in_array($key, array('x', 'y', 'z'))) {`

Comment: This should work, what does your `$row` variable look like?

Comment: Your code works for me. It skips keys `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Comment: It works here: http://ideone.com/vs7sll.

Comment: I don't get it, do want to skip when the key is 'x', as your question says, or do you want to skip when the key is NOT 'x', 'y', or 'z', as the code shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some in_array action.

```
$csv = array();

foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
    if (in_array($key, array('x','y','z'))) continue;

    $csv[] = $val . ',';
}
```

Comment: This is a better way to do it, but if the OP's code does not work, neither will this.

Comment: I read his wrong. I thought it was x && y || z. You're right.

Comment: Abandon all hope; I'm out.